# Rails - Order index by complex sort

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

How do I order my index results by `featured_end_date >= Time.now()` in `:asc` order and then have the rest of the results sort by by `publish_at: :desc`.

Currently I have `BlogPost.order(featured_end_date: :asc, publish_at: :desc)`. I am missing that `>= Time.now()` comparison.

I assume scopes might need to be used, but I am not sure how to achieve this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

BlogPost model

```
scope :featuredfuture, -> { where("featured_end_date >= ?", Time.now()).order(featured_end_date: :asc) }

scope :other,          -> { where("featured_end_date < ? or featured_end_date is null", Time.now()).order(publish_at: :desc) }
```

Controller

```
@blogposts = BlogPost.featuredfuture + BlogPost.other
```

Comment: Perfect, Thanks @Pablo.

Answer (score 1):

You need to specify your collection before ordering. You have to use `where`.

```
BlogPost.where('featured_end_date >= ?', Time.now).order(featured_end_date: :asc, publish_at: :desc)
```

Comment: Not exactly what I wanted. I want to have all the records in the collection, but since they are not all featured I want the featured ones first (as long as they are not expired), then list all the unfeatured and expired ones (ordered by publish_at) following the featured ones.

Comment: I think it would be easier if you define a scope for each set of conditions, then make a method to concatenate those results, like: `featured + unfeatured + expired`